# Node save with multiple taxonomy field of different vocabulary in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, taxonomy

I'm trying to create a node with php with `node_save`. I have three field of taxonomy term of different vocabulary in content type so I'm not able create a node of content type with php.
This is my code.

```
global $user;
$tid = 3; //Different vocabulary
$tid1 = 66;//Different vocabulary
$tid2 = 940;//Different vocabulary
$term_id = 1265; //Different vocabulary
$node = new StdClass();
$node->title = 'Tips 4 Life';
$node->type = 'tips_for_life';
$node->body = 'test';
$node->field_tip_text['0']['value'] = $value['value'];
$node->status = 1;
$node->format = 1;
$node->moderate = 0;
$node->promote = 0;
$node->sticky = 0;
$node->revision = 0;
$node->name = $user->name;
$node->comment = 0;

$node->taxonomy = array($tid => $tid ,$term_id => $term_id,$tid1 => $tid1,$tid2 => $tid2);

$node = node_submit($node);
$done = node_save($node);
if($done)
{
drupal_set_message("done");
}
else {
drupal_set_message("Not done");
}
```

pls help me

Answer (score 0):

`$node->taxonomy` is stored in the following way:

```
[taxonomy] => Array
    (
        [2] => stdClass Object 

            (
                [tid] => 2
                [vid] => 2
                [name] => Descrip 1
                [description] => 
                [weight] => 0
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [tid] => 1
                [vid] => 4
                [name] => Descrip 2
                [description] => 
                [weight] => 0
            )

    )
```

Have you tried the following:

`$node->taxonomy[] = array( etc etc etc )`